# SSO SAML event hooks

Tags: authentication, saml

I'd like to know if there's some kind of "hooks" feature in Salesforces SSO with SAML, so I could be able to subscribe to authentication/authorization changes programatically from other systems (for example: revocation, claims change, etc.).

Comment: Hooks - no, you have to do that yourself. The meat of the implementation can be based on [SCIM](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.identity_scim_rest_api.htm&type=5). Take a look at [Data Integration decision guide](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/data-integration) for options.

Comment: @identigral Thank you. The problem with this approach is it involves doing *polling* and I'd like to avoid this...

Comment: You can make it event-based. It's not out of the box, that's the _no, you have to do that yourself_ part.